# set opacity of the dialog box outside without changing the dialog box opacity in javafx

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

I have to set the opacity only to the outside of the message box, but when I change the opacity, outside and message box both change.

Here is the Code:

```
package com.home.fxmessage;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MessageController {
    @FXML
    protected void handleExitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
        Stage stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

}

package com.home.fxmessage;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MessageController {
    @FXML
    protected void handleExitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
        Stage stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

}

package com.home.fxmessage;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class AppLaunchController {

    @FXML
    protected void handleMessageOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader popupLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
                    "/com/home/views/appMessage.fxml"));
            Stage popupStage = popupWindow(popupLoader, event);
            popupStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Stage popupWindow(FXMLLoader popupLoader, ActionEvent event)
            throws Exception {

        StackPane popupStackPane = (StackPane) popupLoader.load();
        Stage popupStage = new Stage();
        popupStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        popupStage.initOwner((Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene()
                .getWindow());
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        popupStage.setWidth(stage.getWidth() - 14);
        popupStage.setHeight(stage.getHeight() - 37);
        popupStage.setX(stage.getX() + 7);
        popupStage.setY(stage.getY() + 30);
        popupStage.sizeToScene();
        Scene popupScene = new Scene(popupStackPane);
        popupScene.setFill(null);
        popupStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        popupStage.setScene(popupScene);

        return popupStage;
    }

}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.home.fxmessage.AppLaunchController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="btnMessage" layoutX="237.0" layoutY="175.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleMessageOnAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="134.0" text="Message" />
      <Button layoutX="237.0" layoutY="42.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="134.0" text="Text" />
   </children>
</Pane>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>

<StackPane styleClass="window-transparent" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.home.fxmessage.MessageController">
   <children>
      <Pane maxHeight="200.0" maxWidth="373.0" minHeight="142.0" minWidth="200.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="373.0" styleClass="popup-container">
         <children>
            <Button layoutX="351.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleExitButtonAction" text="X" />
            <TextField layoutX="67.0" layoutY="15.0" />
            <TextField layoutX="68.0" layoutY="40.0" />
            <TextField layoutX="68.0" layoutY="65.0" />
            <TextField layoutX="68.0" layoutY="90.0" />
            <TextField layoutX="68.0" layoutY="115.0" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
   <stylesheets>
      <URL value="@style.css" />
   </stylesheets>
</StackPane>
```

style.css

```
.popup-container {
     -fx-effect: dropshadow(two-pass-box, derive(#000, -30%), 4, 0.5, 0.5, 0);
     -fx-background-color: #fff;
     -fx-border-color:#303030;
     -fx-border-width: 1;

}

.window-transparent{
    -fx-background-color: #000000;
    -fx-opacity:0.6;

}
```

I already added "-fx-opacity:1.0;" to "popup-container" but message box opacity won't change. so is there way to set only the outside opacity?

Comment: `root.setStyle("-fx-opacity:0.6");` works for me. Can you create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your scenario.

Comment: Did you try above code?

Comment: Hi jewelsea, its not my requirement...